# Ingest Junit xml report in PyTest

Tags: xml, junit, pytest

Is there a way to integrate the results of a junit test report into PyTest.
The idea would be to point pytest to a junit report and pytest reading it and displaying the results.
Is this possible?

Thanks
Jaydeep